# nodejs disconnect mongoose connection after operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose script to connect to the local db and do some operations. But i have problem disconnecting it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/mydb`);
const userModel = {
      country: { type: String }
      newField: { type: String } 
     };
const myUsersModel = mongoose.model('user',userModel); 

myUsersModel.find({country:"USA"})
    .then(users => users.forEach(function (doc) {


        // some operations
        doc.save();
        db.disconnect();
}));
```

the problem is that the script doesn't disconnect the mongoose connection.
Could somebody help to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/somedb', { useMongoClient: true })

//do stuff

db.close()

Comment: i get `TypeError: db.close is not a function` error

Comment: try db.connection.close()?